# Insert post by php in Wordpress using WPML

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, post, wpml

i am retrieving some posts in Wordpress, from another site.
I have the post in italian and in english.

Now my question: how can i insert the post (and its translation) in Wordpress, by php and mysql, if i have also the WPML plugin?

Thanks to all

Comment: i thing learn this plugin detail and now i send one link check it https://wpml.org/documentation/support/wpml-tables/

Comment: i know this plugin a lot, and i've done it. but i can't get the function wpml_get_content_trid work